# Python list of dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this list of dictionary

```
dictList = [
    {'value': 'me'}, {'value': 'you'}, {'value': 'him'},
    {'value': 'her'}, {'value': 'them'}, {'value': 'they'}
]
```

I know how to get the value given the key like this

```
print(item for item in dictlist if item["value"] == "me").next()
```

which prints out

```
{'value': 'me'}
```

However I want to print just the 'me' 'you' etc and not 'value'. So the result looks like

```
{'me', 'you', 'him', 'her','them', 'they'}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's how you want to have your data structured?

Comment: The result you want is a `set`, so the original ordering will be lost

Answer (score 4):

```
for d in dictList:
    if 'value' in d:
        print d['value']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the values you are looking for with a list comprehension, or use it as a generator expression if you don't need to preserve it

```
[d['value'] for d in dictList if 'value' in d]
```

this will only do the `d['value']` lookup if the key `'value'` exists in the dict

If you *know* that all of the dicts will have that key, you can drop the filter

```
[d['value'] for d in dictList]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to collect `values()` from all dictionaries in the list. This will work
 regardless of what keys are used (you use "value").

```
>>> dictList = [
    {'value': 'me'}, {'value': 'you'}, {'value': 'him'},
    {'value': 'her'}, {'value': 'them'}, {'value': 'they'}
]
>>> [dct.values()[0] for dct in dictList]
['me', 'you', 'him', 'her', 'them', 'they']
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using `reduce`

If you like very unreadable method, here is one:

```
>>> reduce(list.__add__, map(dict.values, dictList))
>>> ['me', 'you', 'him', 'her', 'them', 'they']
```

Explained:

`dict.values`: this is method, which is usually applied to a dictionary in the
way: `{"key": 12, "sleutel": 44}.values()` and returns only values for all the keys in the dict,
thus `[12, 44]`.

By `dict.values` we refer explicitly to that method and call `map` to apply this to each item in
your `dictList`.

From `map(dict.values, dictList)` you get `[['me'], ['you'], ['him'], ['her'], ['them'], ['they']]`.

Then you add one sublist to another.

`['me'] + ['you'] + ['him'] + ['her'] + ['them'] + ['they']`

To do that on a list, use `reduce`, which takes works in the way:

```
>>> res = ['me'] + ['you']
>>> res = res + ['him']
>>> res = res + ['her']
>>> res = res + ['them']
>>> res = res + ['they']
```

and finally you get what you asked for.

### Using `sum`

The solution can be shortened by means of `sum` providing initial value of `[]`:

```
>>> sum(map(dict.values, dictList), [])
>>> ['me', 'you', 'him', 'her', 'them', 'they']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another list of dicts problem! Try using the pandas package to simply refer to keys as column headers and group values using the same key:

```
import pandas as pd

dictList = [
{'value': 'me'}, {'value': 'you'}, {'value': 'him'},
{'value': 'her'}, {'value': 'them'}, {'value': 'they'}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(dictList)
dictList_values = df['value'].tolist()
```

Added some benchmarking, using pandas outperforms on large scale sets. Here I've created a set with 200k entries as a "large" case. The small case is the given 6 entries:

```
setup_large = "dictList = [];\
[dictList.extend(({'value': 'me'}, {'value': 'you'}, {'value': 'him'},\
    {'value': 'her'}, {'value': 'them'}, {'value': 'they'})) for _ in range(25000)];\
from operator import itemgetter;import pandas as pd;\
df = pd.DataFrame(dictList);"

setup_small = "dictList = [];\
dictList.extend(({'value': 'me'}, {'value': 'you'}, {'value': 'him'},\
    {'value': 'her'}, {'value': 'them'}, {'value': 'they'}));\
from operator import itemgetter;import pandas as pd;\
df = pd.DataFrame(dictList);"

method1 = "[d['value'] for d in dictList if 'value' in d]"
method2 = "df['value'].tolist()"

import timeit
t = timeit.Timer(method1, setup_small)
print('Small Method LC: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))
t = timeit.Timer(method2, setup_small)
print('Small Method Pandas: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))

t = timeit.Timer(method1, setup_large)
print('Large Method LC: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))
t = timeit.Timer(method2, setup_large)
print('Large Method Pandas: ' + str(t.timeit(100)))

#Small Method LC: 0.000217914581299
#Small Method Pandas: 0.00168395042419
#Large Method LC: 3.89074897766
#Large Method Pandas: 0.189871072769
```